# Matillion ETL not launching

Tags: amazon-ec2, matillion

I am trying to launch a Matillion ETL instance through AWS and keep getting the error below

**ERROR: This site can’t be reached amazonaws.com took too long to respond ec2-34-226-233-122.compute-1.amazonaws.com**

This is the youtube video I follow. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=piL4THHpxxY&t=254s

Everything works perfectly. I created the stack just as the lady in the video did (I even created my own keypair and everything. I did not use the same primary subnet and security group as the lady in the video though as she blurs hers out. I believe this might be the problem but as I am very new to AWS I am not sure.

Here are pictures of my stack info. When I click on the link in the third picture I receive the error message I posted above. I did not include the parameters field picture but if anyone thinks they need it to help I can include it just let me know.

Any help is much appreciated!

[image: image 1]

[image: pic_2]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agreed with your initial analysis, it's most likely related to your choice of Security Group (i.e. firewall), made around 5m28s into the video.

First of all, I strongly recommend you use https:// rather than http:// as the video shows.

Then you will need to make sure your new Matillion instance allows inbound network access for HTTPS (port 443) from your own IP address.

To do this in the AWS console, start at the EC2 service page

- Make sure you are in the correct Region (use the dropdown top right)
- Go to Security Groups under Network & Security.
- Click into the Security Group you chose while launching the stack
- Find the Inbound rules section, and press the Edit Inbound Rules button

If you don't see any line that already permits you access, then you'll need to add a new inbound rule

- Press the Add Rule button
- Choose HTTPS and set the Source to "My IP". It will automatically fill in your own IP address
- Press the Save Rules button

[image: Allowing inbound HTTPS access]

The change should take effect immediately, and you should be able to reach your Matillion instance at https://...amazonaws.com using a web browser.

A couple of final pointers:

- Your browser will likely complain about the security risk of an unknown TLS certificate. It's safe to click through this and proceed to the site because you know it's your own Matillion server
- Whenever your own IP address changes - which might happen every few days depending on your internet provider - then you'll have to grant yourself access again from your new IP address

Comment: Awesome thank you so much. These type of things sometimes go over my head as my focus is more data analytics. Much Appreciated!